# Duplicate Module Name: react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I ran `Pod Update` in my XCode Project and now my project isn't compiling due to duplicate modules being downloaded. Anyone know any solutions?

```
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/.../App/Finalv2 


Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph...jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native
  Paths: /Users/.../App/Finalv2/node_modules/react-native/package.json collides with /Users/.../App/Finalv2/ios/Pods/React/package.json

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
Loading dependency graph, done.
```

**UPDATE:**
I deleted my `node_modules` folder and `package.lock.json` and ran `npm install` but the issue is still there

**EDIT:**

Adding my `Package.json`

```
{
  "name": "sample-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.2.2",
    "art": "^0.10.1",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "expo": "^24.0.2",
    "firebase": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.3",
    "native-base": "^2.3.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.3",
    "react-native-camera": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "git+https://github.com/kk1429/react-native-circular-progress.git",
    "react-native-countdown-circle": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.16",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.18.5",
    "react-native-fcm": "^11.2.0",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-linkedin": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-material-ui": "^1.19.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.471",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-pull-refresh": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-rename": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-svg-animated-linear-gradient": "^0.1.8",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-tag-input": "git+https://github.com/kk1429/react-native-tag-input.git",
    "react-native-thumbnail-video": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
    "react-native-video": "^2.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.19",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-save-refs": "^1.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-persist": "^5.3.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.1.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Running `npm install` gives a weird error

```
> fsevents@1.2.4 install /Users/.../App/Finalv2/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/.../App/Finalv2/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> grpc@1.10.1 install /Users/kaaddevelopers/Documents/Clipme/App/Finalv2/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.1.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

Comment: are you using `react-native-router-flux`?

Comment: No. I am not using that. I am using `react-native-navigation`

Comment: Please add your `package.json` so that i can see which libraries do you have!

Comment: Done. Edited the Post

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I just spent some time searching around for a solution and finally found something that worked! I'm not using Firebase, but the discussion here was able to help: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/414 You have to add two lines to your Podfile.

```
# Add these to your Podfile
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
```

Then run the following to make sure you reinstall your CocoaPods.

```
cd ios
rm -rf Pods
pod install
```

Comment: Just for the other people coming across this post: This solution worked for me (deleting and re-installing the pods was crucial). Maybe it should be the accepted answer? Thanks Dehli!

Comment: Thanks @Dehli, really helpful your solution. Only need an extra command after pod install `react-native start --reset-cache`.

Comment: Thanks m8. It was very helpful. I'm using both Firebase and Bugsnag on my project and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

1. `watchman watch-del-all`
2. `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*`
3. `erase jest-cache folder`
4. `rm -rf node_modules`
5. `npm install`
6. `npm cache clean && npm start -- --reset-cache`

**Update**

Also try to [download the latest node js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and run `npm install -g npm`

Comment: Can you rollback the `Pod Update`?

Comment: I guess I will have to create a new project and import the source code from scratch :/

Comment: This worked for me. I am using expo to run my app for reference. All the other solutions never worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

remove the "React" folder inside of your "Pod" folder

add this inside of your pod file at the bottom after the last `end`

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

# The following is needed to ensure the "archive" step works in XCode.
# It removes React & Yoga from the Pods project, as it is already included in the main project.
# Without this, you'd see errors when you archive like:
# "Multiple commands produce ... libReact.a"
# "Multiple commands produce ... libyoga.a"

    targets_to_ignore = %w(React yoga)

    if targets_to_ignore.include? target.name
      target.remove_from_project
    end

  end
end
```

remove your `Pods` folder and then go 
`pod install`

Comment: It'll be re-added after every `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Dehli's answer, this could happen if:

1. You have react-native as 'dependency' for a react-native module

   Solution: Move react-native to 'peerDependency' in package.json
2. You've moved to peerDependency and have your application's package-lock.json listing react-native as a dependency to your module

   Solution: Delete package-lock.json in your application, clean npm_modules folder and run `npm install` again

Answer (score 0):

In my case, because I linked a library by pod, so it auto install react to pods. So I updated my podfile:

```
target 'MyProject' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
   'Core',
   'CxxBridge',
   'DevSupport',
   'RCTActionSheet',
   'RCTAnimation',
   'RCTGeolocation',
   'RCTImage',
   'RCTLinkingIOS',
   'RCTNetwork',
   'RCTSettings',
   'RCTText',
   'RCTVibration',
   'RCTWebSocket',
 ]
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
//Another libraries here
  pod 'RNImageTools', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-tools-wm'


  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

      # The following is needed to ensure the "archive" step works in XCode.
      # It removes React & Yoga from the Pods project, as it is already included in the main project.
      # Without this, you'd see errors when you archive like:
      # "Multiple commands produce ... libReact.a"
      # "Multiple commands produce ... libyoga.a"

      targets_to_ignore = %w(React yoga)

      if targets_to_ignore.include? target.name
        target.remove_from_project
      end

    end
  end

end
```

Then I remove `Pods` folder and run `pod install`.
That alls.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue is that there are more that one copy of `react-native` module in your watch folders (including the projectRoot).

1. You can delete those duplicate ones by reinstallation, like many answers suggested.
2. If can't, ignore others through [blacklist](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration/#blocklist) option