# how to solve the problem of "folly/Portability.h" and "File .../main.jsbundle does not exist" in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

When I want to compile my IOS application for production I have this error that appears: `'folly/Portability.h' file not found` and `echo 'error:this File .../main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with`
I have searched the Internet to solve this problem but I can't solve it

here is the information of react-native:

```
  React Native Environment Info:
System:
  OS: macOS 10.14.4
  CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
  Memory: 38.35 MB / 8.00 GB
  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 10.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
  npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
  Android SDK:
    API Levels: 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
    Build Tools: 25.0.0, 26.0.0, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.1, 27.0.3, 28.0.3
    System Images: android-18 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-19 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-22 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-24 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-25 | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a, android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.5429.30.34.5452501
  Xcode: 10.2.1/10E1001 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3 
  react-native: ^0.59.6 => 0.59.6 
npmGlobalPackages:
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
  react-native-rename: 2.4.1
```

here is the configuration of my Pods

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AppXYZ' do

  # Pods for AppXYZ

  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.15.0'

  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
  pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo'

  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'
  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'AppXYZTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

To solve the first problem (`'folly/Portability.h'`) I found on the internet this ( but it doesn't work)

```
      # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
```

and to solve the second problem I found this: 
`react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/assets`
but it doesn't work, it generates another error for me:

```
Loading dependency graph...error jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native
  Paths: .../ios/Pods/React/package.json collides with .../node_modules/react-native/package.json
```

these lines will have to solve this problem (but it does not solve)

```
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'
```

someone can help me because I'm stuck

Comment: In the same boat with a fresh react-native app from their cli.  Added the gesture handler pod and suddenly required to adjust react-native: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805753/duplicate-module-name-react-native.  Running your "solve the second problem" finished successfully but actually running the app fails with the folly error still.

Answer (score 6):

just drag & drop Folly folder to "Header Search Paths" box in Build Settings tab from Pods project setting and rebuild. see pic below

[search header path setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsVJY.png)

Comment: thank for your answer but i resolve it, I created a new project and I made copies and pasted. I know, it wasn't the best solution.